# CMIS Visitor pattern for copying folder structure multithreaded?

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, alfresco, cmis

I would like to copy a specific folder structure from one instance of Alfresco to another.

This folder structures includes huge amount of data which should moved, but only this one which are not older than 30 days.

I thought to implement a visitor pattern based java tool which iterates through the folder structure. If the node was visited I would lock the node and go forward, if it wasn't visited I would copy the node to the other instance.

Is this a good Idea or do somebody have other ideas, or experiance with that?

Regards
Kaffi

Comment: First of all why would you like to 'copy' to another instance. Can't you just create a new contentStore where you store it to so it's still in the same Alfresco?

Comment: The problem is we need copy the data which is not older than 1 month. Therefore the classic way is not an option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMIS doesn't know how to lock a folder node. It only knows how to checkout documents.

What if you use the cmis:objectId as a key and the path as a value, then for folders that match your criteria, write the key-value pair to a key-value store, like redis. I'm proposing something like redis rather than an in-memory structure like a hashmap due to your comment that your structure is huge and that you might have multiple processes traversing the hierarchy looking for folder nodes meeting your criteria.

Then you can have one or more "consumer" processes reading from the key-value store and for each object it finds, use the path to re-create the folder structure in the target repo.

Comment: Dear Jeff
It's honor that you answer my question. Your idea sounds very interesting.
Is it possible to create whole folder structures with CMIS if parent folder does not exist? If the order in Redis is not well defined?

Comment: I have forgot to mention that I need also apply aspects on the copied node. If a specific condition is set.

Comment: That's not a problem. You can add the aspects when you create the node. CMIS 1.1 supports aspects natively, but in CMIS they are called "secondary types". Also, another tool you could look at to meet this requirement is Apache Camel with the camel-cmis component.